# I am getting SFHFKeychainUtilsErrorDomain error - 25299

Tags: ios, keychain, sfhfkeychainutils

I am trying to store the values into keychain by using SFHFKeyChain. But i am getting below error (This error is pop only in iOS 8.1 ).

[image]

can any one know about this error. Why this error is showing. Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Trace through the SFHFkeychain code to see exactly where the error is occurring. If you include 3rd party code you must take ownership, understand and maintain.

Comment: You need to show your code along with failing input data.